# How to write product of three sums

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, summation

I know that by the binomial theorem,

$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n \right)= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \left(\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k} x^n\right)$. How do I write the product of three sums

$\displaystyle \left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_nx^n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty b_nx^n \right)\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty c_nx^n \right)$?

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The first one isn’t the binomial theorem; it’s just an instance of the [Cauchy product](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cauchy_product).

$$\large\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}a_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}b_nx^n\right)\left(\sum_{n\ge 0}c_nx^n\right)=\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{{i+j+k=n}\atop{0\le i,j,k\le n}}a_ib_jc_kx^n$$

Comment: Whoops! You're right, it isn't binomial theorem. Thank you!

Comment: @Sarah: You’re welcome!

Answer (score 1):

Let $w_n=\sum_{k=0}^n a_kb_{n-k} x^n$ then do the same as above for the $(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} w_nx^n)(\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} c_nx^n)$